# How to show matches for dates that match date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following situation:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| date       | event     | start_date | duration(days) |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-01 | concert   | 2010-01-01 | 2              |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-02 | NULL      | NULL       | NULL           |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-03 | workshops | 2010-01-03 | 3              |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-04 | NULL      | NULL       | NULL           |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-05 | NULL      | NULL       | NULL           |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-06 | NULL      | NULL       | NULL           |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-07 | NULL      | NULL       | NULL           |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-08 | festival  | 2010-01-08 | 5              |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| 2010-01-09 | NULL      | NULL       | NULL           |
+------------+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

Now, I need to display the above information in the way that for every date row when a particular event is happening its name is shown in an event column, not only on the first day when it starts.

There are three tables, one with *DATES* only, one with *EVENTS* and one with the *START_DATES* and *DURATION* of each event.

So far I have been only able to produce a table like above but I have no idea how to replace NULL values with event name for each day of the duration of the event.

```
SELECT d AS date, event, start_date, duration 
FROM dates 
LEFT JOIN info ON info.start_date=d.date AND city='LA' 
LEFT JOIN events ON events.event=info.event 
WHERE d BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-09'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share the query you have

Comment: SELECT d AS date, event, start_date, duration 
  FROM dates 
  LEFT JOIN info ON info.start_date=d.date AND city='LA' 
  LEFT JOIN events ON events.event=info.event
    WHERE d BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-09'

Comment: Can you consider changing the design? instead of saving start date and duration, can you save start date and end date? That will make your life much easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below - created a subquery that shows all events with their start date and end date, then joined to the full list of dates:

```
SELECT d.date, t.event, t.start_date, t.end_date
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT e.event, i.start_date, i.start_date + INTERVAL i.duration DAY AS end_date
            FROM events e
            JOIN info i
                ON e.event = i.event
            WHERE i.city = 'LA'
            ) t
    ON d.date BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
WHERE d.date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-01-09'
ORDER BY d.date, e.event_name;
```

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot change the design. 
There seems to be a problem since in 
  ON e.event = d.event
the d table with dates does not have any column that would relate to events. It has only dates which relate to start dates in info table

Comment: @tabaluga - sorry, fixed now.

Comment: Hard to believe how fast and accurate you are @Galz !
Thank you very much for your help, I'm gonna make sure I get it right next time!